# Anyone have an English Translation of Abarbanel on Bereishis 1:27?

Tags: women, parashat-bereishit, abarbanel

Anyone know of an English translation available of the Abarbanel's commentary on Perek 1, Passuk 27 of Bereishis?

Comment: Is there a specific section you're trying to understand?